# Adding elements to array into nested loop

Tags: ruby

I am trying to add elements to an array, and then push it to a hash. I need following output

```
{:jan=>"jan", :feb=>"jan", :mar=>"jan", :apr=>"jan", :cont=>["j", "a", 
 "n"]}
{:jan=>"feb", :feb=>"feb", :mar=>"feb", :apr=>"feb", :cont=>["f", "e", 
 "b"]}
{:jan=>"mar", :feb=>"mar", :mar=>"mar", :apr=>"mar", :cont=>["m", "a", 
 "r"]}
{:jan=>"apr", :feb=>"apr", :mar=>"apr", :apr=>"apr", :cont=>["a", "p", 
 "r"]}
```

Here is my code:

```
arr = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr']
cont = []

arr.each do |f|
 cont.clear
 f.split('').each do |t|
  cont << t
 end

 hash = {jan: f, feb: f, mar: f, apr: f, cont: cont}
 trending_repos.push(hash)
end

puts trending_repos
```

In the first iteration, it pushes the array that I want to see at the last. Here is the output:

```
{:jan=>"jan", :feb=>"jan", :mar=>"jan", :apr=>"jan", :cont=>["a", "p", 
 "r"]}
{:jan=>"feb", :feb=>"feb", :mar=>"feb", :apr=>"feb", :cont=>["a", "p", 
 "r"]}
{:jan=>"mar", :feb=>"mar", :mar=>"mar", :apr=>"mar", :cont=>["a", "p", 
 "r"]}
{:jan=>"apr", :feb=>"apr", :mar=>"apr", :apr=>"apr", :cont=>["a", "p", 
 "r"]}
```

Comment: You are clearing the `const` each iteration. This clears, adds to it, then clear... You to rearrange the order you are doing things.

Comment: @ForeverZer0yes because I need to empty array before nested each. I have figure out. Instead of `cont.clear` I need to move `cont = []` inside first loop.

Comment: I see now, I was thinking the `end` for the inner-loop was the close of the outer block. :P

Comment: Clearing the array was clearing all of them, so they would all be equal to the result of the last iteration.

Answer (score 4):

This is all you need to do.

```
keys = arr.map(&:to_sym)
  #=> [:jan, :feb, :mar, :apr]
arr.map { |s| { **keys.product([s]).to_h, cont: s.chars } }
  #=> [{:jan=>"jan", :feb=>"jan", :mar=>"jan", :apr=>"jan", :cont=>["j", "a", "n"]},
  #    {:jan=>"feb", :feb=>"feb", :mar=>"feb", :apr=>"feb", :cont=>["f", "e", "b"]},
  #    {:jan=>"mar", :feb=>"mar", :mar=>"mar", :apr=>"mar", :cont=>["m", "a", "r"]},
  #    {:jan=>"apr", :feb=>"apr", :mar=>"apr", :apr=>"apr", :cont=>["a", "p", "r"]}]
```

See [this article](http://wizardofogz.com/ruby/2015/10/02/ruby-double-splat.html) for a good discussion of Ruby's double-splat operator for hashes. In short, `{ **{ a: 1 }, b: 2 } #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}` is analogous to the single-splat operator for arrays: `[*[1,2],3] #=> [1,2,3]`.

Comment: Or `arr.map { |s| {**arr.map { |k| [k.to_sym, s] }.to_h, cont: s.chars }}` to avoid hardcoding.

Comment: @Amadan, good suggestion. I implemented a little differently (then edited again, unable to resist the double-splat).

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out whats wrong with my code. I need to move declaration of array `cont` inside first loop. Here is correct code.

```
arr = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr']

arr.each do |f|
 cont = []
 f.split('').each do |t|
   cont << t
 end

 hash = {jan: f, feb: f, mar: f, apr: f, cont: cont}
 trending_repos.push(hash)
end
```

Comment: Yes, another reference/value issue.